# Search and replace using the filename

Tags: regex, search, replace, filenames

I'm trying to do a search and replace over multiple files where I find something like: `<form>` and replace it with something like: `<form id="fileNameForm">`

So for example if the filename was "helloWorld.html" it would replace `<form>` with `<form id="helloWorldForm">`

Comment: What's langue you used, shell script or others ? Is there just on form in the file?

Comment: Any language that could do it. Shell script if that'll work.  And yes, just one form per file.

Answer (score 0):

```
[kerwin@fedori ~]$cat replace.sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in `find -name '*.html'`
do
id=`echo $file | sed -r 's#.*\/([a-z]+)\.[a-z]+#\1#i'`
`sed -i "s#<form>#<form id=\"$id\">#i" $file`
echo $file -----ok!
done
```

execute it in the same folder